# CDS size impact on startup performance

Tags: java, performance, jvm

In order to improve the startup of our application we use the class-data sharing (CDS) feature of Java. Currently it works great, because we load a lot of classes, especially in the start phase of the application.

Pre-condtion:

- We run on Linux with CFS
- During the startup of the device / application there is a cpu/io-contention situation
- We have several measurement points in the application, which will trigger an event in order to signal that some functionality has been loaded correctly.
- Create CDS archive with a list of 7_000 loaded classes
- Create CDS archive with a list of 9_000 loaded classes

Result:

- When using the archive with 7_000 loaded classes, reaching the first point takes at average 14 seconds. The second will be reached after 50 seconds.
- When using the archive with 9_000 loaded classes, the first point will be reached after 15 seconds (avg / 1 second regression). The second measurement will be reached 7 seconds faster.

Problem:
One second regression for the first event

I understand why the second point will be reached faster. This is because many classes will be placed in the CDS archive and will not need any linking, verify, etc. while classloading. But I can not understand why the first point will suffer a one second regression compared to the archive with 7_000 classes.

What reasons could be responsible for the regression?

Assumption

- more IO? (need to verify with Kernel-Trace)

Comment: Profiling with `perf` would be more useful than playing a guess game.

Comment: @apangin Thank you for your advice. I will have a look whether I am able to get perf running in given environment.

Comment: I can't tell you what may be responsible, but maybe JVM log messages can help. Check out [-Xlog](https://blog.codefx.org/java/unified-logging-with-the-xlog-option/) and launch with the `-Xlog:class+load:file=cds.log` option, then check the `cds.log` file and try to spot the regression there. Maybe that puts you on the right path.

Comment: It’s not surprising that moving more work before the first point raises the time to reach it. The real question is, why on Earth does it matter when the actual goal to reduce the overall startup time has been reached?

Comment: @Holger, thank you for your time. Maybe I should have been more precise in describing my requirements. I will update the question regarding. Basically I have an application, which contains multiple goals. Each goal must be reached at a given time, therefore there is no "overall startup". Could you please elaborate more on "moving more work before first point"?

Comment: The kind of work that has to be done, is touching too many implementation details and is not really important. If the execution time between point one and two decreases when integrating 2000 more classes into the archive, it implies that work connected to them (loading and initializing) happened between these two points, but now, has been saved thanks to the archive. So now, they are loaded and prepared in whatever way as part of the archive, hence, before point one. You can try to find out, which actual work is responsible, but the choice still is either, to include the classes or not.